# How to Algorithmically Generate a List of Probabilities

Tags: python, probability

Please forgive my lack of statistical nomenclature.

I've been given an arbitrary list of values to sample, currently:
`list_to_sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
At this point, it doesn't matter what the list contains, but that the length of list is 5.

And, I've been given a list of almost arbitrary "pareto-like" probabilities, currently:
`probability_list = [0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]`
(pareto-like as it does not follow the 80-20, but rather 80/40 as the top 80% of probable selected values will be in the top 40% of the list.

I am now trying to generalize this, so that if `list_to_sample` gets longer, like:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`
I can extend the `probability_list` and maintain the same curve.

I am trying to use `np.pareto.pdf` to produce a list of probabilities that is similar to:
`[0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]`
and where the sum of the list (the sum of the probabilities) equals 1.

Specifically, I have tried this:

```py
import numpy as np

list_to_sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output = np.array([pareto.pdf(x=list_to_sample, b=1, loc=0, scale=1)])
```

Output:

```
[[0.5        0.125      0.05555556 0.03125    0.02      ]]
```

I have tried changing parameters to no avail. I was hopeful that by changing parameters I could get pareto to produce the desired result. So far, no luck.

Perhaps there is a better function to produce (or extend) a list of probabilities.

Comment: I can't figure out from your description if you tried the updated `list_to_sample` and got an unexpected result, or if something else went wrong

Comment: At least 2 things are wrong with the output of [0.5 0.125 0.05555556 0.03125 0.02 ]: 
#1 this output doesn't have the desired probability where 80% is the top 40%
#2 this output doesn't sum to 1

So, I am trying to figure out how to algorithmically generate a probability list that is very similar to [0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05] using pareto (or something else)

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to normalize the output. If you do, the top 40% account for 85% of the distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the Pareto distribution? If so, I don´t think this problem is well-defined as the items in `list_sample` ***will matter*** and I don´t see from your question how you can define all the parameters of the Pareto distribution.

If you can use other techniques, I would go with a simple interpolation, for example the [cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)). Since you said the values in the list don´t matter, we can work with the percentage values instead.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

list_to_sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
probability_list = [0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]

# --- adding zero at the beginning to ensure the we map zero to zero

x = np.array([0] + list_to_sample) / len(list_to_sample)
y = np.array([0] + probability_list).cumsum()

print("x:", x)  # -- [0.0  0.2  0.40  0.60  0.80  1.0]
print("y:", y)  # -- [0.0  0.5  0.80  0.90  0.95  1.0]

# - spline

spline = sp.interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y)

new_values = np.arange(1, 11)
cprobs = spline(new_values / len(new_values))

print("New values:", new_values)
print("Cumulative probabilities:", cprobs)

# -- the top 40% still has an overall 80% probability,
# -- the output below is rounded

# -- [   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10]
# -- [0.27 0.50 0.68 0.80 0.87 0.90 0.93 0.95 0.97 1.00]


# - to get the probability for each value we just diff cprobs

probs = np.diff([0] + list(cprobs))
print("Probabilities:", probs)

# -- [0.272 0.228 0.178 0.122 0.067 0.034 0.026 0.024 0.024 0.026]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. This was super helpful. Adding a sort forces the trailing probs into order. Thank you again

Comment: Indeed the `list_to_sample` must be sorted. You will also need to slightly modify the answer if there are duplicates in your input.